# Is it possible to make a function parameter optional by condition?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
type TestType<A> = [A] extends [never] ? void : A

class Singleton<T, A> {
    private ClassRef: (new (...args: A[]) => T)
    private args: TestType<A>
    private _instance?: T

    constructor(ClassRef: (new (...args: A[]) => T), args: TestType<A>) {
        this.ClassRef = ClassRef
        this.args = args
    }

    public get instance() {
        if (!this._instance) {
            this._instance = new this.ClassRef(this.args as A)
        }

        return this._instance
    }
}

class Empty {}

const test = new Singleton(Empty)
```

If I specify

```
type TestType<A> = void
```

then the compiler does not swear.
But if I do it conditionally
I get an error "Expected 2 arguments, but got 1."

Comment: What do you expect from `TestType` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to replace the argument with a variadic tuple type. If `A` is `never`, we evaluate `TestType` to be an empty tuple. If not, `TestType` resolves to a tuple with a single element containing `A`.

```
type TestType<A> = [A] extends [never] ? [] : [args: A]

/* ... */

constructor(ClassRef: (new (...args: A[]) => T), ...args: TestType<A>) {
    this.ClassRef = ClassRef
    this.args = args
}
```

Here are some tests:

```
class Empty {}
class NotEmpty {
  constructor(arg: string) {}
}

const test1 = new Singleton(Empty)
const test2 = new Singleton(NotEmpty) 
//                          ^^^^^^^^ Error: Arguments for the rest 
//                                   parameter 'args' were not provided
const test3 = new Singleton(NotEmpty, "abc")
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwbggHgIID4oF4oG10BdKCAD2AgDsATeAqiANwgCcSB%20AkgLgIENWAc3h9iAKHEBjADb949AMoBLKkJkRgAeyqoYAGihYoAb3FQLUMK2VN%20lKAGE5CgEoQAZnwAUjAO5Q3gB0IYIiYvhEAJS42DBR5pbWtvbQYaKwCEgoGJiJFsl2DgD6qoj8VFIQHHwwkpZQUjqIrACuUtqs3s7y8O5egf6BIUHpEdGxsFGGI2OZiMiQuTFmDQ3AABbK8EE9bp64Ti59nvlrm9ujwvR46WcAvvVJrQBGMspSUEKaUGXAFVVvCszg1lB5AgBCC47UpUcqVCDAtbIqDQoKw%20FVQ5DNF7E4ebxo9JQeRGBIoqCPEGWViaVqsKiorYwv4AiAPcRU2S9KAAUQAtmBQKZHtyFFAAHJaYACoUgUyJJpw4BtDpaLphPgtVRCFaPLnNYCorLYiABFRqDTaKjeWWgBJKxDGxAAJlN5p1Vp03ilMsF9ukhudwAAzO6oBb1Jpvb67SBDAAifgvKQJqJAA)

Comment: Thanks a lot! The decision surprised me. But I still don't understand why my solution didn't work.